# Exception on creating a DotNetFactory object on UFT

Tags: c#, vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to create a DotNetFactory.CreateInstance Object using UFT 12.02.

Below is the code:

```
Set obj = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance(namespace.Class, C:\namespace.dll)
```

while running this I am getting an error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Can anyone please help me on getting this resolved?

NOTE:
1. I am trying to create an object of a dll object of a application which is already installed. I do not have access to the code.
2. Microsoft .Net framework 4.5.1 is installed in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax should be

`DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("Namespace.ClassName","<complete path of the dll>")`

If the constructor of the class requires any arguments,

`DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("Namespace.ClassName","<complete path of the dll>", arg1,arg2,arg3)`